# autocomplete with jquery and mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am trying to make the following code to work with results from mysql database table. The autocomplete suggestions will come from the database table. I have tried to make a foreach loop with mysql but it didn't work.

What is the easiest way to do what I want?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I use the following code for the connection with database results. But i can not make it work in jquery array.

```
require_once("resource/Database.php");
$query ="SELECT username FROM users";
                $select = $db->prepare($query);
                    $select->execute(array());  
            foreach($select as $rs) :   

echo "\"".$rs['username']. "\",<br>"; 

endforeach;
```

ps: Guys, if you think this question is dublicate, you must tell me where is the original one. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your server side code?

Comment: This?
$query ="SELECT username FROM users";
    $select = $db->prepare($query);
     $select->execute(array());  
   foreach($select as $rs) :

Comment: Edit that into the question pls, do not addit as a comment!

Comment: Also, your jquery code does not point to the php file.

Comment: Now you see. But it doesnt work.

Comment: I have added my php code aswell now. But Whereever I put the result, it doesn't work.

Comment: Lol. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The duplicate question demonstrates what you need to do to point the autocomplete to the php file and how you need to encode the results of the sql query.

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work. This is not the same problem.